# Substituir colunas de uma linha quando outra coluna começar com uma palavra específica

Tags: shell-script, awk

Preciso substituir uma letra de uma coluna toda vez que ela encontre uma palavra específica no arquivo.

Exemplo: Nas linhas abaixo, sempre que encontrar a palavra PEDRO em uma linha na coluna 4 , tenho que substituir o "P" por "E" na coluna 8.
Ou seja, podem vir como "PEDRO HENRIQUE" mas preciso que detecte somente a parte do PEDRO.

```
"1234556","123123123","0000021152","PEDRO","20011101",1000,100,"P","",10,"MG",500,"??",0,"R06A0","ABC"
"1234565","123123123","0000004517","ALBERTO","20010401",1000,500,"E","G",1,"% ",400,"ML",1000,"P01B0","DGK"
"12312312","123123","0000005334","CARLOS","20010701",3000,100,"E","",30,"MG",50,"??",0,"N05C0","AAA"
"11236","1245545423","0000021152","PEDRO RICARDO","20011101",1000,100,"P","",10,"MG",1500,"??",0,"R06A0","ABC"
"123123123","123123123","0000011011","RAFAEL","20010901",100,100,"E","",1,"G ",100,"ML",1000,"J01D2","FPB"
"123123123","12312312312","0000018102","RONALDO","20011001",4800,100,"P","",48,"??",0,"??",0,"N02B0","ACA"
"11236","1245545423","0000021152","PEDRO HENRIQUE","20011101",1000,100,"P","",10,"MG",1500,"??",0,"R06A0","ABC"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

`awk -F, '$4=="\"PEDRO\"" {$8="\"E\""}1' OFS=, nomeDoArquivo`

Explicação:

Primeiro configuramos o delimitador para ser o caracter vírgula, visto que é um arquivo do tipo CSV.

A expressão verifica se a quarta coluna é igual a `"PEDRO"` e caso positivo substitui o valor da oitava coluna por "E". Foi necessário escapar essas aspas, visto que no exemplo que você deu todos os elementos estão com aspas.

O número 1 no final diz que é pra printar a linha de qualquer forma, tenha havido modificação, ou não.

Resultado com o exemplo dado:

```
«~» $ awk -F, '$4=="\"PEDRO\"" {$8="\"E\""}1' OFS=, teste
"1234556","123123123","0000021152","PEDRO","20011101",1000,100,"E","",10,"MG",500,"??",0,"R06A0","ABC"
"1234565","123123123","0000004517","ALBERTO","20010401",1000,500,"E","G",1,"% ",400,"ML",1000,"P01B0","DGK"
"12312312","123123","0000005334","CARLOS","20010701",3000,100,"E","",30,"MG",50,"??",0,"N05C0","AAA"
"123123123","123123123","0000011011","RAFAEL","20010901",100,100,"E","",1,"G ",100,"ML",1000,"J01D2","FPB"
"123123123","12312312312","0000018102","RONALDO","20011001",4800,100,"P","",48,"??",0,"??",0,"N02B0","ACA"
"11236","1245545423","0000021152","PEDRO","20011101",1000,100,"E","",10,"MG",1500,"??",0,"R06A0","ABC"
```

Edit pedido no comentário:

Para aceitar quaisquer valores na quarta coluna começados com PEDRO, e não exatamente iguais a PEDRO, precisa-se mudar a condição para uma expressão regular.

Use:

```
awk -F, 'match($4, /PEDRO/) {$8="\"E\""}1' OFS=, teste
```

A função match verifica se o item da coluna especificada se encaixa com o padrão fornecido, no caso, começando com `"Pedro` e terminada com `"`, tendo quaisquer combinações de caracteres no meio.

Novamente, as aspas precisaram ser escapadas, e a expressão `.*` representa quaisquer combinações de caracteres.

Comment: Obrigado pela rápida resposta! Creio que me faltou detalhar um pouco mais. Minha primeira pergunta rs

Comment: O arquivo é .txt, e a linha que vem a palavra pedro pode vir com mais coisa: "1234556","123123123","0000021152","PEDRO henrique","20011101",1000,100,"P","",10,"MG",500,"??",0,"R06A0","ABC"                                   "1234556","123123123","0000021152","PEDRO goncalves","20011101",1000,100,"P","",10,"MG",500,"??",0,"R06A0","ABC"                               "1234556","123123123","0000021152","PEDRO 123123123","20011101",1000,100,"P","",10,"MG",500,"??",0,"R06A0","ABC"                           Entao eu preciso que detecte somente o Pedro, pra modificar a outra coluna.

Comment: Neste caso, de clarificação, creio ser melhor editar a pergunta, para adicionar mais coisas no final, e ficar mais legível do que nos comentários. Além disso, não tem problema a extensão do arquivo propriamente dita. O arquivo tendo os campos separados por vírgula já o caracteriza, teoricamente, como um arquivo csv. Nesses casos colocar a extensão só explicitaria a situação.

Comment: Perfeito. Já Editei, se tiver alguma ideia de como fazer, agradeco muito !

Comment: Editei a resposta. Verifique se agora funciona para suas necessidades. Caso positivo, não se esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita, para a pergunta ficar como resolvida, e ajudar eventuais buscas no site.

Comment: Nao funcionou =( Nao se se interfere que haja símbolos como % ou . na coluna q vem a palavra pedro.                                                                                                                                      "0002115203","0000052487","0000021152","PEDRO ABCD AB F.C 5.00%MG x 10","20011101",1000,100,"P","",10,"MG",500,"??",0,"R06A0","ABC"

Comment: Simplifiquei um pouco a resposta, para ser mais genérica. De qualquer forma, ela funcionava com o exemplo que você deu. Também funciona com o exemplo que você deu no último comentário. Para evitar esse tipo de confusão, o correto é incluir sempre um exemplo verificável na pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado mais uma vez pela ajuda. Então, percebi que ao executar no terminal esse comando awk -F, 'match($4, /PEDRO/) {$8="\"E\""}1' OFS=, text.txt ele mostra o resultado correto, mas nao edita o arquivo, é como se mostrasse só como deveria ser o resultado.

Comment: É só adicionar ```>text.txt``` no final do comando, então.

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou. Só para clarificar para quem tenha a mesma dúvida. Tive que concatenar para outro arquivo.   Ficando assim: awk -F, 'match($4, /PEDRO/) {$8="\"E\""}1' OFS=, text.txt > text2.txt